# How can I filter the exact interface in huawei switch?

Tags: switch, huawei

How can I filter the exact interface in huawei switch?

you see when I use the `include GigabitEthernet0/0/1` to filter, there will get 
many `GigabitEthernet0/0/1*` interfaces:

```
<Z178A>dis interface brief | include GigabitEthernet0/0/1  
PHY: Physical
*down: administratively down
#down: LBDT down
(l): loopback
(s): spoofing
(b): BFD down
(e): ETHOAM down
(dl): DLDP down
(lb): LBDT block
InUti/OutUti: input utility/output utility
Interface                   PHY   Protocol  InUti OutUti   inErrors  outErrors
GigabitEthernet0/0/1        up    up           0%  0.01%          0          0
GigabitEthernet0/0/10       up    up        0.12%  0.13%          0          0
GigabitEthernet0/0/11       up    up           0%  0.01%          0          0
GigabitEthernet0/0/12       up    up           0%  0.01%          0          0
GigabitEthernet0/0/13       up    up        0.17%  0.03%          0          0
GigabitEthernet0/0/14       up    up           0%  0.01%          0          0
GigabitEthernet0/0/15       up    up           0%  0.01%          0          0
GigabitEthernet0/0/16       up    up           0%     0%          0       5281
GigabitEthernet0/0/17       down  down         0%     0%          0          0
GigabitEthernet0/0/18       down  down         0%     0%          0          0
GigabitEthernet0/0/19       down  down         0%     0%          0          0
```

when I use the `GigabitEthernet0/0/1\s` I can not filter the `GigabitEthernet0/0/1` out.

```
<Z178A>dis interface brief | include GigabitEthernet0/0/1\s
PHY: Physical
*down: administratively down
#down: LBDT down
(l): loopback
(s): spoofing
(b): BFD down
(e): ETHOAM down
(dl): DLDP down
(lb): LBDT block
InUti/OutUti: input utility/output utility
Interface                   PHY   Protocol  InUti OutUti   inErrors  outErrors
<Z178A>
```

so, who can help me with this? I want to filter out the exact interface `GigabitEthernet0/0/1`.

---

```
<Z178A>dis interface brief | ?                             
  begin    Begin with the line that matches
  exclude  Match the character strings excluding with the regular expression
  include  Match the character strings including with the regular expression
```

---

**EDIT-01**

I tried the `display interface brief  | i ^XGigabitEthernet0/0/1 +` but still not work.

```
[Z178A]display interface brief                       
PHY: Physical
*down: administratively down
#down: LBDT down
(l): loopback
(s): spoofing
(b): BFD down
(e): ETHOAM down
(dl): DLDP down
(lb): LBDT block
InUti/OutUti: input utility/output utility
Interface                   PHY   Protocol  InUti OutUti   inErrors  outErrors
Eth-Trunk1                  up    up        2.80%  2.60%          0          0
  GigabitEthernet0/0/49     up    up        2.92%  2.82%          0          0
  GigabitEthernet0/0/50     up    up        2.68%  2.38%          0          0
Eth-Trunk100                down  down         0%     0%          0          0
GigabitEthernet0/0/1        up    up           0%  0.04%          0          0
GigabitEthernet0/0/2        up    up           0%     0%          0          0
GigabitEthernet0/0/3        up    up           0%     0%          0          0
GigabitEthernet0/0/4        up    up        0.01%  0.01%          0          0
GigabitEthernet0/0/5        up    up           0%  0.02%          0          0
GigabitEthernet0/0/6        up    up           0%     0%          0          0
GigabitEthernet0/0/7        up    up           0%     0%          0          0
GigabitEthernet0/0/8        up    up           0%  0.04%          0          0
GigabitEthernet0/0/9        up    up           0%  0.04%          0          0
GigabitEthernet0/0/10       up    up        0.08%  0.06%          0          0
GigabitEthernet0/0/11       up    up           0%  0.01%          0          0
GigabitEthernet0/0/12       up    up           0%     0%          0          0
GigabitEthernet0/0/13       up    up        0.07%  0.02%          0          0
GigabitEthernet0/0/14       up    up        0.08%  0.02%          0          0
GigabitEthernet0/0/15       up    up           0%  0.04%          0          0
GigabitEthernet0/0/16       up    up           0%     0%          0       5281
GigabitEthernet0/0/17       down  down         0%     0%          0          0
GigabitEthernet0/0/18       down  down         0%     0%          0          0
GigabitEthernet0/0/19       down  down         0%     0%          0          0
GigabitEthernet0/0/20       down  down         0%     0%          0          0
GigabitEthernet0/0/21       down  down         0%     0%          0          0
GigabitEthernet0/0/22       down  down         0%     0%          0          0
GigabitEthernet0/0/23       down  down         0%     0%          0          0
GigabitEthernet0/0/24       down  down         0%     0%          0          0
GigabitEthernet0/0/25       down  down         0%     0%          0          0
GigabitEthernet0/0/26       down  down         0%     0%          0          0
GigabitEthernet0/0/27       down  down         0%     0%          0          0
GigabitEthernet0/0/28       down  down         0%     0%          0          0
GigabitEthernet0/0/29       down  down         0%     0%          0          0
GigabitEthernet0/0/30       down  down         0%     0%          0          0
GigabitEthernet0/0/31       down  down         0%     0%          0          0
GigabitEthernet0/0/32       down  down         0%     0%          0          0
GigabitEthernet0/0/33       down  down         0%     0%          0          0
GigabitEthernet0/0/34       down  down         0%     0%          0          0
GigabitEthernet0/0/35       down  down         0%     0%          0          0
GigabitEthernet0/0/36       down  down         0%     0%          0          0
GigabitEthernet0/0/37       up    up           0%     0%          0          0
GigabitEthernet0/0/38       up    up           0%     0%          0          0
GigabitEthernet0/0/39       up    up           0%     0%          0          0
GigabitEthernet0/0/40       up    up           0%     0%          0          0
GigabitEthernet0/0/41       up    up           0%     0%          0          0
GigabitEthernet0/0/42       up    up           0%     0%          0          0
GigabitEthernet0/0/43       up    up        4.94%  5.34%          0          0
GigabitEthernet0/0/44       up    up           0%     0%          0          0

[Z178A]display interface brief  | i ^XGigabitEthernet0/0/1 +  
PHY: Physical
*down: administratively down
#down: LBDT down
(l): loopback
(s): spoofing
(b): BFD down
(e): ETHOAM down
(dl): DLDP down
(lb): LBDT block
InUti/OutUti: input utility/output utility
Interface                   PHY   Protocol  InUti OutUti   inErrors  outErrors
```

Comment: `dis interface brief | include GigabitEthernet0/0/1$`. `$` means the end of the line. It will work if Huawei fully supports regular expressions.

Comment: I tried this, not work.

Comment: Ah. How about `dis interface brief | exclude 1[0-9]` or `dis interface brief | include \w*0\/0\/1\b\s+`

Comment: there will filter out the 2*.

Comment: Next solution `dis interface brief | exclude \/[2-9]|\/[0-9]{2}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like Huawei CLI supports Regular Expressions, so matching *one or more spaces* after the interface name is your best bet.

On my switch:

```
<Huawei>display interface brief  | i ^XGigabitEthernet0/0/1 +
PHY: Physical
*down: administratively down
#down: LBDT down
(l): loopback
(s): spoofing
(E): E-Trunk down
(b): BFD down
(e): ETHOAM down
(dl): DLDP down
(lb): LBDT block
InUti/OutUti: input utility/output utility
Interface                   PHY   Protocol  InUti OutUti   inErrors  outErrors
XGigabitEthernet0/0/1       up    up        0.02%  0.02%          0          0
```

Where the `^` matches the *start of the line* (you can omit this, I think), while `<space>+` means "match _one or more spaces".

Comment: it do not work too, see my edited post.

Comment: @244boy In your case the interfaces are _not_ 10GbE, so you should use `^GigabitEthernet` and not `^XGigabitEthernet`